# Disable Link while animated Basket

Tags: jquery, shopping-cart

I'm using this script for my online shopping basket: http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/fly-to-basket-effect-with-jquery/.

Like people suggest in the comments it's easy buggy when you click multiple times on the same image. How can I disable the img link when it's clicked once and re-enable it when the product is added to the basket?

I've tried setting the attribute HREF of  to # in the beginning of the function, but that doesn't help.

So when a user clicks the function needs to be executed, but the link should be disabled as long as the function is busy.

thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the begining of the onclick handler, check for a busy flag. Then set the busy flag to true. Then, in the callback for the ajax method, set the busy flag back to false.

```
var busy = false;

$('#myLink').click(function(e){
    if(busy) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    busy = true;
    //make ajax call

    $.ajax {..., function(){
        //in ajax callback
        busy = false;
    }}
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've changed my code (you can see it at http://code-bin.homedns.org/700) but that doesn't help. I can keep clicking which makes it crash.

Comment: The line `busy=false;` needs to appear within the callback function declared in the ajax call in the line `success: function(theResponse) {`.

Comment: here you go, better late then never ;). btw check my new question :p