# how to limit the number of items added to basket in fly to basket plugin?

Tags: jquery, shopping-cart

I am referring to a previous question here . I was implementing a fly to basket effect in the shopping cart implementation in my web page ,its all working fine , but one problem is that ,we can click on add to cart link as many times we want , i want to restrict this or otherwise i just want to limit the number of items added to basket to 20 , How can i achieve this ?

I just given a limit when adding items to basket through ajax ,and its working fine when clicking slowly one by one . But when clicking speedly its crashing as its not stopping when the items cross the limit 20 , It should just stop the animation and addtobasket function to add the items to database when its over 20

the link is here :[Disable Link while animated Basket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064886/disable-link-while-animated-basket)

Comment: this is the direct link : http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/fly-to-basket-effect-with-jquery/.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could simply disable the button as you reach certain number. I have small test: 
`jsfiddle example`